# Error: NewInstance failed to find a match for id = tcp while using ActiveMQ

Tags: c#, activemq-classic

I'm using Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ v5.18.2 to run the ActiveMQ Example Publisher code in C#, but I'm getting:

```
Apache.NMS.NMSConnectionException: 'Error creating transport.' Exception: NewInstance failed to find a match for id = tcp
```

Here's my code:

```
String host = env("ACTIVEMQ_HOST", "localhost");
int port = Int32.Parse(env("ACTIVEMQ_PORT", "61616"));

String brokerUri = "activemq:tcp://" + host + ":" + port;

NMSConnectionFactory factory = new NMSConnectionFactory(brokerUri);

IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection(user, password); // error occurs here
```

I tried with different versions (downgraded) of ActiveMQ nuget package starting with the latest version 2.1.0, but nothing worked.

Comment: Odd that you are getting that error, because it means the scheme 'tcp' is registered, but returning a null factoryType. I suspect it is an issue in the solution-- not having aligned versions of API and ActiveMQ NMS and .NET runtime version. I suggest opening a JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/ to get the attention of the maintainers.

Answer (score 1):

My solution here was to:

1. Remove all NMS package references and make sure these were also removed in the .csproj file(s).
2. Add package reference to **Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ** 2.1 (NOTE: ONLY this package as this references 2.0 of **Apache.NMS**)
3. Review binding redirect, in my case, I did not need it so I removed an old entry from my .config file

Answer (score 0):

**Resolution: Use version 2.0.0 of Apache.NMS and Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ**

I had the same issue today.  Turns out Version 2.1.0 of the NuGet packages have only been out for about 2 months (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Apache.NMS/2.0.0).

ActiveMQ
Versions 5.17.3 and 5.18.3

C# Packages: (that don't work)
Apache.NMS          Version="2.1.0"
Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ Version="2.1.0"

C# Packages: (that DO work)
Apache.NMS          Version="2.0.0"
Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ Version="2.0.0"